# How do I show page 1 on index.vue using nuxt?

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

[image]

I have the following dynamic page structure where index.vue would redirect to exchange/view/market/1 to show the first page. How do I show the first page on index.vue itself without redirecting while loading page 2 on exchange/view/market/2 using Nuxt? Any direction would be appreciated

Comment: Just make your page content in a component and use it in _page and in index

Comment: @Aldarund I think he means a Router View

Comment: Onltly the _page should have the underscore, everything else should be normal. The underscore turns it into a parameter with the name of the underscored path.